# podman-compose rootless container fails at system boot

Tags: podman, podman-compose

I've installed podman rootless and podman-compose in RHEL8

If I start my container as 'user1' with the following command everything works fine:

```
cd /home/user1/project
podman-compose up -d
```

but if I reboot the VM the container is not starting automatically:

```
ERRO[0000] error joining network namespace for container xxx: error retrieving network namespace at /tmp/podman-run-5038383/netns/cni-aa8a2008-a67a-3a26-c16f-1f279e5f88ac: unknown FS magic on "/tmp/podman-run-5038383/netns/cni-aa8a2008-a67a-3a26-c16f-1f279e5f88ac": 58465342 
Error: error joining network namespace of container xxx: error retrieving network namespace at /tmp/podman-run-5038383/netns/cni-aa8a2008-a67a-3a26-c16f-1f279e5f88ac: unknown FS magic on "/tmp/podman-run-5038383/netns/cni-aa8a2008-a67a-3a26-c16f-1f279e5f88ac": 58465342
```